# Issue implementing this Carousal in HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I want to achieve the above carousal in this video on my own website using HTML,CSS and JS.
All have seen are either React Packages, I am not using React but pure HTML

[image: carousal section I want to implement]

[Link to site that has this carousal](https://getprospa.com/)

This is my own design which i want to implement the above carousal

[image: My own design which I want to replicate that carousal here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust all the sizes as you need.

```css
#carousel {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 20px;
}


/* All .slide 10%... */

.slide {
  flex-basis: 10%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: flex-basis 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* ...except first .slide 50% */

.slide:first-child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}


/* When #carousel is hovered, all .slide 10%... */

#carousel:hover .slide {
  flex-basis: 10%;
}


/* ...except hovered .slide 50% */

#carousel:hover .slide:hover {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.slide image {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/600/300/cat?random=1"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/600/300/cat?random=2"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/600/300/cat?random=3"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/600/300/cat?random=4"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/600/300/cat?random=5"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/600/300/cat?random=6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the first image (flex-gow:2), i.e take 50% of the width while the remaining 5 takes 10% each. Then once each image is hovered, it increase the width to 50% (only the current image been over).

Comment: Of course, see may edited answer.